# What controller files read the checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I need to override the controller file that is used on the checkout page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout controller files used

**Location:**

magento223\vendor\magento\module-checkout

**Files**

**Checkout Page**

Magento\Checkout\Controller\Index - Index

** **This file handles most of the checkout business logic** **

Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage.php

**Checkout Success Page**

namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage - Success.php

**Checkout Failure Page**

namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage - Failure.php

You need to go through these links for checkout customization

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-customize-checkout/